# webpack import a es6 module, it return an empty object?

Tags: webpack, babel-loader

I wrote a package in es6, and committed it with npm.

when I try to import it, it just return a empty object.

the ***package code*** like this:

```
// package: someone-package
// dirs:
// - src
//   - index.js
// - package.json
// someone-package/src/index.js
export default {foo:'bar'}

// someone-package/package.json
{
  "name": "someone-package",
  "main": "./src/index",
  ...
}
```

***webpack.config.js***:

```
// webpack.config.js
export default {
  entry: {app: './entry.js'},
  module: {
    rules: {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }]
    }
  },
  // other config fields ignore here.
}
```

the ***entry script*** like this:

```
// entry.js
import someone from 'someone-package';
console.log(someone) 
// print {}
```

why it does't print {foo: 'bar'}

when I try this, it work well:

```
// entry.js
import someone from 'someone-package/src/index';
console.log(someone)
// print {foo:'bar'}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `package.json` file you have to specify entry file: `"main": "dist/main.js"`.